# Unity UI-Builder VisualElement picking doesn't cover whole element

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having some issues with picking in Unity's UI-Builder (2019.4)

I customized the Node class from the GraphView namespace to allow for trees to go from top to bottom as opposed to Unity's standard left to right.

The issue comes in when I try to use ports. I changed the port flexDirection to Column for the input port and ReverseColumn for the output port. Those are all the changes I did.
Now when I try selecting the port, all I can pick is the first half on the input port and the second half on the output port (regardless of flexDirection).

[image: picking problem]

I take it this is something done specifically for Ports, **but I can't find a way to make the entire element be pickable**. There is also no element in the hierarchy that seems to be causing this behavior.